# Посоветуйте азиатские маркеты для андройд приложения?

Tags: android

Я насколько знаю у китайцев нет дуступа к Google Play.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Основных маркета три(в порядке популярности):

1. [应用宝](http://sj.qq.com/)(Myapp) от Tencent
2. [360手机助手](http://zhushou.360.cn/)(360 Mobile Assistant) от "Qihu 360"
3. [手机助手](http://shouji.baidu.com/)(Baidu Mobile Assistant) от Baidu

Ориентироватся нужно прежде всего на них. Остальные маркеты используются на довольно малом количестве устройств и/или завязаны на производителя(как например [Huawei App Store](http://appstore.huawei.com/)).